# How to create relationship in neo4j fast

Tags: neo4j

Today I have create 591,113 nodes in my neo4j. Then I want create relationships on them using following code:

```
MATCH (A), (B)
WHERE A.value = B.value
CREATE (A)-[:SameValue]->(B)
```

But this took me for hours(and I have to terminate it before it finish).
And I want to ask how to create relationship on a big amount of nodes fast?

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
MATCH (a:UseLabels)
WITH a
MATCH (b:UseLabels{value:a.value})
CREATE (a)-[:SameValue]->(b)
```

It only matches values that match and avoid the cartesian product.

Comment: Beat me by 19 seconds! ;)

Comment: You mentioned indexes though, that could have saved you that 19 seconds. I've got labels though. You can have my vote!

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this approach. It did work faster. But a node (a) would link back to itself. How to avoid this situation ? I've tried ` MATCH (a:Labels) WITH a MATCH (b:Labels{value:a.value}) WHERE b.othervalue <> a.othervalue CREATE (a)-[r]->(b) ` It slow down again.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have indexes on the `value` properties?

This also might work better (still, indexes are important):

```
MATCH (a:A) WITH a
  MATCH (b:B {value: a.value})
  CREATE a-[:SameValue]-b
```

Comment: I found that it take a long time (in fact it make my neo4j crashed) to create index on a.value.